# SQL Server 2008 R2 connection on a VmWare Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, instances, vmware-fusion

Here is the scenario I am facing.

1. I have installed Windows 7 Professional on a VMWare.
2. Installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I launch the Server Management Studio and try to connect to the instance I get the following error

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)"

Now, I installed all the packages of SQL server with default settings. The only change that I had done is selected a mix-mode for authentication.

I setup a similar instance on a desktop and it works fine. Before posting it here I have searched on the web and made sure all the services, ports and protocols are enabled/running.

But I still cannot seem to connect, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally found the solution the above mentioned problem. Not sure why, but when I give the instance name pre-appended with .\ it works fine.

```
.\<INSTANCENAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have a default instance installed?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx

Comment: The 1st time I tried with the default settings I got a different error, then I got some expert advice and then reinstalled with providing a instance name.

Comment: @vksvicky Sounds like there is no default instance, just the named instance.  Only a default instance can be connected to without specifying an instance name.

Comment: By default if you don't provide a name, MSSQLSERVER is the name of the instance, isn't it?

Comment: @vksvicky Connecting to .\<INSTANCENAME> is working, then that's not the default instance.  If you also installed a default instance then connecting to (local) should work.  What is in your registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL